# jQuery DataTable column resizes automatically when displaying inline edit field

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Alright Ill try to be as articulate as I can. I am using dataTables 1.9.4 and I am working with a table that I would like to have be a specific height, in this table I have 5 columns 2 of which are hidden columns, while the other 3 are visible.

That said in one of the 3 columns I two div elements one that is just plain text version of what I want users to be able to edit. Where when they click on that name/title to edit it, that div hides and the other one in the same column shows. The one showing has an input element and a link that says cancel. If cancel is clicked then the reverse happens the now hidden shows and the visible hides.

Everything works as expected so no real problems with any of that. The problem is it appears something to do with one or more of the following being set in the datatables api.

`sScrollY`, `bAutoWidth`, and a maybe a few others. cause the columns to resize when i hide/show  the divs respectively in any given row, if the overall data in the column is larger than what was originally there hiding. Either way I have found that setting `sScrollY` is the main culprit if I let the table just be whatever size it wants to be height wise. Then the table won't try to auto correct its width per column every "re-draw"

Or I could remove the input field, though that goes against the spec of whats wanted/needed.

So my overall question is, after trying to set/unset, play with and tweak each setting of the api I use for this table. Is, is there anything.. I can do to keep the height set for the overall table while offering an inline element?

```
   var oTable = $('#the_table').dataTable({
        //"sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bFilter": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        //"sScrollY": "200px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "aaSorting": [[1,'desc'],[0,'desc']],
        "oLanguage": {
            //"sInfo": 'Tasks: _END_',
            //"sInfoEmpty": 'No Job/Task(s).',
            "sInfo": '',
            "sInfoEmpty": '',
            "sEmptyTable": ' ',
        },
        "aoColumns": [
              { "bSortable": true, "bVisible": false, "iDataSort": 0, "aTargets": [ 2 ]},
              { "bSortable": true, "bVisible": false},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"67%", "sClass":"hide_overflow"},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"30%"},
              { "bSortable": false, "sWidth":"3%", "sClass":"rgt"}
           ]
    });
    return oTable;
```